# Ссылка на файл json фармата в коде js

Tags: javascript, json

В папке проекта я создал файл с json с названием data.json. В этом файле записан например подобный код

```
[
    {
        "bar": "Snickers",
        "kilocalories": "390",
        "img": "/img/img_info.bmp"
    },
    {
        "bar": "Bounty",
        "kilocalories": "390",
        "img": "/img/img_info.bmp"
    },
    {
        "bar": "twix",
        "kilocalories": "390",
        "img": "/img/img_info.bmp"
    }
]
```

Далее я хочу изъять из этого файла данные json в массив (js), но как в скрипте делать ссылку на файл и т.д.. По сути вопрос простой но не смог найти на него ответ, так что прошу прощения.

Comment: Мало входных данных. В какой среде код исполняется? Браузер? Нода? Если браузер, то не вариант. Если нода, то там `fs.readFile` читает файл. В общем, надо больше подробностей о том, какая проблема решается.

Answer (score 1):

Измените расширение с `data.json` -> `data.js`.

В `data.js` экспортируйте ваш массив:
`export const array = [...]`

В скрипте импортируете массив `import { array } from 'path'`